# I want to make a Pie chart in blackberry with Google API's?

Tags: blackberry, pie-chart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display a pie chart in blackberry application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514119/how-to-display-a-pie-chart-in-blackberry-application)

I have tired so far the bar chart but I don't want that I just want to make a PIE Chart with Google API's. Any Help regarding this is appreciable!!

Thanks,
Ahmad

Comment: check the answer of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this  [Creating Pie chart in BlackBerry](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/userGuide/pieCharts/normal2d/index.html) .it will give you some needful info ..
   here is the useful link for [PI Chart](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/userGuide/pieCharts/normal2d/index.html)